# SQL aggregate function MAX remove duplicates with joining

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table **tblAccess**:

```
+-----------+-------+-----------+
| lClientID | lData | datAccess |
+-----------+-------+-----------+
|         1 | test1 |  5.6.2019 |
|         1 | test2 |  8.6.2019 |
|         2 | test3 | 15.6.2019 |
|         2 | test4 | 15.6.2019 |
|         2 | test5 |  3.6.2019 |
+-----------+-------+-----------+
```

I wanted to extract the last data is related to each client but i have problem with the duplicates.
My SQL-query is:

```
SELECT * FROM tblAccess AS t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT lClientID, MAX(datAccess) AS datLastDate FROM tblAccess GROUP BY lClientID) AS t2 ON t1.lClientID = t2.lClientID AND t1.datAccess = t2.datLastDate
```

What i have:

```
+--------------+-------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| t1.lClientID | lData | datAccess  | t2.lClientID | datLastDate |
+--------------+-------+------------+--------------+-------------+
|            1 | test2 | 08.06.2019 |            1 |  08.06.2019 |
|            2 | test3 | 15.06.2019 |            2 |  15.06.2019 |
|            2 | test4 | 15.06.2019 |            2 |  15.06.2019 |
+--------------+-------+------------+--------------+-------------+
```

What i need (remove duplicates, it should select any item test4/test3 - it doesn't matter):

```
+--------------+-------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| t1.lClientID | lData | datAccess  | t2.lClientID | datLastDate |
+--------------+-------+------------+--------------+-------------+
|            1 | test2 | 08.06.2019 |            1 |  08.06.2019 |
|            2 | test4 | 15.06.2019 |            2 |  15.06.2019 |
+--------------+-------+------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Thanks in advance!

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=caf1fe4ce7232f643d6be29a9f3ffbf3)

Comment: BTW, Hello everyone. The forum removes it from main post (

Comment: If lData field is unimportant, why include it in output? Why do you need same data in multiple columns? A simple aggregate query with GROUP BY will return the maximum date for each lClientID.

Comment: I added a dbfidlle to your post, and only see 2 lines in the output. It's unclear what you want.

Comment: @Luuk: your fiddle is based on strings, not dates

Comment: Ok, this one uses dates: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=04dd26de61154ebc2dc16989e12ca467 . Also the query return values as John requested.

Comment: Does your table have a primary key?

Comment: @Luuk, I use MS-ACCESS database and it returns the duplicates.

Comment: @June7, this data is IP addresses and because of the logging time is quantized sometimes it can return the same time for the subsequent queries. I need to get the last access time. Therefore the subsequent rows have the same lData field values and it unimportant what the one i select.

Comment: @Wolfgang Kais, the real table has the more fields and has the primary key column 'Id'.

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58467211/how-to-properly-create-a-sql-query/58467496#58467496

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the results using `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from tblAccess as a
where not exists (select 1
                  from tblAccess as a2
                  where a2.lClientID = a.lClientID and
                        (a2.datAccess > a.datAccess or
                         (a2.datAccess = a.datAccess and
                          a2.ldata > a.ldata
                         )
                        )
                 );
```

Note:  this doesn't return the last two columns which seem to be duplicates of the previous two.

Comment: how to use your query if lData has null values? Because in this case it returns 2 rows. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Solved. I used the next query: `SELECT a.*
FROM tblAccess AS a
WHERE not exists (select 1
                  from tblAccess as a2
                  where a2.lClientID = a.lClientID and
                        (a2.datAccess > a.datAccess or
                         (a2.datAccess = a.datAccess and
                          a2.Id > a.Id
                         )
                        )
                 );
`

Answer (score 0):

As any item will do

This should work

```
SELECT t1.lClientID, Max(t1.lData), Max(t1.datAccess), t2.lClientID, t2.datLastDate 
FROM tblAccess AS t1 INNER JOIN 
(SELECT lClientID, MAX(datAccess) AS datLastDate FROM tblAccess GROUP BY lClientID) 
AS t2 ON t1.lClientID = t2.lClientID AND t1.datAccess = t2.datLastDate
GROUP BY t1.lClientID, t1.datAccess, t2.lClientID, t2.datLastDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to get the rows with the maximum `datAccess` and remove the duplicates (if any) by getting the maximum (or minimum if it is not important) of `lData`:

```
SELECT t.lClientID, MAX(t.lData) AS lData, t.datAccess 
FROM tblAccess AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM tblAccess
  WHERE lClientID = t.lClientID AND datAccess > t.datAccess 
)
GROUP BY t.lClientID, t.datAccess
```

There is no point for returning the columns again (like the join you use), right?
 You only need the 3 columns of the table.
Results:

```
lClientID   lData   datAccess
1           test2   8/6/2019
2           test4   15/6/2019
```

Comment: Thank you for reply! I'll use this solution. I wanted to ask yet another one - how to change the query if the table has two fields lData and lData2 and i need to return the both fields? Thank you in advance!

Comment: If it is not important if the column values are from the same row then add `max(lData2)` to the select list. If you want both column values from the same row then you need more conditions in the subquery inside NOT EXISTS, something like Gordon's answer. And if there are other columns too then these conditions should be extended further. But a proper solution for this case would be to have a unique column like `id` in each row which would be used to identify each row.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I'll consider Gordon's solution!

Comment: When you post a question you should expect answers for the requirement that you set. Changing the requirement of the original question invalidates the answers that you get. This is not how it works.

Comment: sorry. Just the original table has the many fields and i wanted to simplify the table. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

Now knowing that your table has a primary key of `Id`, the problem could be solved like this:

```
SELECT lClientID, lData, datAccess FROM tblAccess
WHERE Id IN (
  SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM tblAccess AS tmp
  WHERE lClientID = tblAccess.lClientID
  ORDER BY datAccess DESC, Id DESC
);
```